# Should I use a Service or a Directive in my Angular.js app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I have read through the documentation of Angular and found that directives should be used for DOM manipulation, and blogs that say they can be used for traversal or anything else DOM related. Then for services it states that they are simply places for reusable code that can be injected into controllers.

I have some JS from a non-Angular app that traverses the DOM and builds up a map of IDs. It doesn't modify DOM. What is the recommended way of doing this? Should I use a directive or a service? From what I know already it doesn't seem to fit either case 100%.

Help and guidance appreciated.

Comment: Directive. Although you should really have your data separated from the DOM, in which case you would work directly with the data in your controllers, instead of reading it from the DOM.

Comment: I actually don't have control over the part of the DOM I am working with. I have to pull the data I want from it first. At the moment I have a buildMap function in my directive which does everything and returns the map of ideas. Should I call this from the controller? But then, are directives meant to be injected into the controller? I thought not.